# To Upload Directory to ownCloud 8.25 in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, owncloud-server

I cannot upload directory to ownCloud 8.25 in WebGui. There was/is a [bug](https://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?t=8128) about it 2013 but it seems to be back now once again.

---

Can you upload directory to ownCloud in Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user ***cannot*** upload a folder through the web browser based `Upload` option.

This is not a bug. This is how file upload function works under browsers (they accept files only).

**Solution**:

Use the desktop client and share the particular folder you want to upload. All subfolders and files will be synced subsequently, thus reducing burden of making folders.

---

**Installing owncloud-client in ubuntu 16.04**

Here is the Official page > [Official page for Owncloud Client installation](https://software.opensuse.org/download/package?project=isv:ownCloud:desktop&package=owncloud-client)

1. Adding the repository.

`sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_16.04/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/owncloud-client.list"`

2. Update package.

`sudo apt-get update`

3. Install the owncloud client.

`sudo apt-get install owncloud-client`

After installation you have to login to the server, and sync with the server. By default this will make a sync folder as,

`/home/$user_name/owncloud`

Now, the user can simply place their folder which they want to sync inside this **owncloud folder**, and it will be synced to the server.

- After sync to server the user can stop to sync  the with local client if they wish. First make a copy of folder elsewhere. Then, just goto to **Owncloud icon** on the top bar,

Right click > `Settings` > uncheck folder you do not want to be synced. (Unchecked folders will be removed from the Local file system !)

Comment: @Masi :  Are you using Ubuntu on your client computer ?

Comment: I found that in `ownclound-client`: you cannot use HTTP in Ubuntu 14.04, but you can use HTTP in 16.04. Why?

Comment: Both 14.04 and 16.04 can use HTTP and HTTPS. No problems.

Comment: Yes, the client is just outdated in server sources of 14.04. It is not so smooth as in 16.04.

Answer (score 2):

You can upload folder without desktop client using webdav protocol.
If your owncloud server is on `example.org/owncloud` then from your file manager go to:

For nautilus or GNOME:
`dav://example.org/owncloud/remote.php/webdav`
or
`davs://example.org/owncloud/remote.php/webdav` for secure connection.

For KDE and Dolphine: `webdav://example.org/owncloud/remote.php/webdav`

And then you can use Owncloud like a local folder e.g. drag and drop your folder there.

Source: https://doc.owncloud.org/server/7.0/user_manual/files/files.html